# Chessgames.com board theme and pieces

Tags: online-chess, pieces, chessboards

What lichess and chess.com setups are the most similar to the board theme and pieces of chessgames.com? I love their setup and I'm feeling the most comfortable with it.

Answer (score 2):

For chess.com, I believe I have found the best setup.[image]

Comparing it to chessgames.com, the piece design is exactly the same and the tan color is extremely close.

[image]

Lichess is a little trickier for the board color, although the pieces are to be found as well.

[image]

The piece type is the third option from the left in the top row.

[image]

As for the board type I chose, it is in the right column, six down from the top.

[image]

Comment: In case it it useful to any readers who need to know chess font names: the font shown for chessgames.com and lichess -- with its four-spike queens, symmetrical bishops and near-straight-necked knights, is called Alpha.